# How to ontrol a 12v dc water valve with battery powered Arduino?

Tags: arduino, solenoid, solenoid-valve

I just want to open/close a valve when the soil moisture sensor reports a pre-determined moisture level, using an Arduino.

The main issue I'm facing is that most valves operate at 12/24 VDC and I'm using 5v to power the Arduino. Those 5v come from a Step-Up MT3608 which is drawing voltage from an 18650 Li-Ion battery.

Is there any way to power a 12v valve without adding a second MT3608? Doing this would make the whole thing electrically inefficient (I need to keep the power consumption low).

[image]

Comment: A MOSFET? A BJT?

Comment: A typical water valve uses a lot of power. You probably want a latching valve, these are less common, I am having trouble finding any right now. After you have picked a valve, then it will be an electrical design problem that people here will help you with.

Comment: Use a latching or indexing relay which change state with a pulse of current to the coil. Use one contact of the relay to feed back to the microcontroller so it can monitor the status.

Comment: Or use a rotary or slide type of valve and mechanically actuate it.

Comment: Looks like a latching valve would work. Thanks everyone!